# Searching for Facebook applications on the graph using Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am working with Python and I have installed the Python SDK so I can work with Facebook Open Graph:

```
pip install facebook-sdk
```

Then I created this simple file with the below code:

```
import facebook

ACCESS_TOKEN = '<MY APP ACCESS TOKEN OBTAINED FROM https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/>'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)

inf = graph.request('search', args={'q': 'bingo', 'type': 'application'})
```

The problem is that I am getting this error:

```
GraphAPIError: (#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint
```

when searching for an application like on the last line of code above, and I can't figure out why. Note that when I run code like:

```
inf = graph.request('search', args={'q': 'bingo', 'type': 'page'})
print inf
```

... everything works fine. i.e: Searching for a page with keyword bingo works fine, but searching for an application with keyword bingo fails.

Does anyone know how to solve this or why it is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The following changes will go into effect on July 10, 2013:](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)

> Graph API search changes
>   App access tokens will be required for all search Graph API calls except Places and Pages. **Search for application will no longer be supported**.

Comment: Thanks so much, okoloBasii. I didn't realize that. Do you know by any chance if there is any way then, to search for applications otherwise? How would someone go about tracking Facebook applications if there is no possibility of searching for them either by keywords or even by browsing through them programmatically without specifying search keyword?